# Setting folder as case-sensitive with fsutil.exe file doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, fsutil

I am trying to make the folder case-sensitive on Windows 10 following one of the many tutorials using fsutil.exe: [How to Enable or Disable Case Sensitive Attribute for Folders in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111293-enable-disable-case-sensitive-attribute-folders-windows-10-a.html)

First I executed command

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

It executed successfully and asked to reboot, which I did. Then I tried to make my target folder case-sensitive with command

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path/to/target/folder> enable
```

... but it responds with

```
setCaseSensitiveInfo is an invalid parameter.
```

whatever I do. I even tried different cases (heh) like SetCaseSensitiveInfo

Here I stuck because I can't google anything relatable and also fsutil documentation doesn't contain anything about setCaseSensitiveInfo for some reason. Any help?

My windows 10 version is 1607 btw

Comment: You enabled WSL and now are trying to make Windows itself case-sensitive (which won't work)? What's the connection? Why are you inventing parameters for fsutil?

Comment: @harrymc: The connection is that this feature was [originally added for WSL purposes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/), and while it can be used for any directory (including non-WSL ones), it only becomes *available* if WSL is installed.

Comment: Please follow the link I provided.

Comment: This is a WSL kludge, do not expect it to work for Windows tools.

Comment: 1607 was released in 2015. Why do you use such an old and unsupported version?

Comment: @phuclv 1607 is still supported as part of LTSC, all the way up to 2026(!)

Comment: @MMM yes, but only if the OP is using the enterprise LTSC version. You don't get that on normal enterprise or home versions

Comment: @phuclv that's what I figured when he mentioned his company's policy in a comment on user1686's answer

Comment: @user1686: I'll believe it when I see it. I have seen Windows applications that "normalized" file names by setting them to lower or upper case. Several decades of applications assuming case doesn't matter are not going to be erased by one kludge.

Comment: @phuclv well, my company simply doesn't want to buy new updates. Unfortunately, this case problem doesn't significant enough. I'm trying to find some workaround, but so far no good

Comment: @Kngh2 Windows 10 updates are free forever. But I do understand that the IT department in many companies are just too preservative or lazy to evaluate new software versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows 10 version is too old. This feature was added in version 1803 (RS4).

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe you know some other way around it, besides updating windows (my company policy doesn't allow it)

Comment: There is no other way around it. Older versions *literally do not have* the feature.